# AngularJS controller logic does not execute

Tags: angularjs

I have a call to an API that verifies the existence of a user. If a user is found it will send 200, otherwise it will send 404. Below is my AngularJS controller. For some reason, via developer tools I see the 404 return from my API but this controller does not follow the programmed logic. It does nothing. When a 200 is received it performs as expected. Any thoughts?

```
  var params = $stateParams.resetToken;
  var foundUser;

  $http.get('/api/user/' + params, {

  })
  .then(function onSuccess (res) {
      foundUser = true;
  })
  .then(function onError(res) {
      if (res.status === 404) {
        foundUser = false;
        $location.path('/lost');
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
  });
```

Comment: a 404 is not considered a success, so the `onSuccess()` callback wouldn't fire.  you should add an error clause and execute your failure code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.catch` to process status 404 responses.

```
  var params = $stateParams.resetToken;
  var foundUser;

  $http.get('/api/user/' + params, {

  })
  .then(function onSuccess (res) {
      foundUser = true;
      //return to chain success
      return res;
  })
  //.then(function onError(res) {
  //USE catch to handle errors
  .catch(function onError(res) (
      if (res.status === 404) {
        foundUser = false;
        $location.path('/lost');
      } else {
        console.log(res);
      }
      //throw to chain rejection
      throw res;
  });
```

The error handler should either be the first argument of the `.catch` method or the second argument of the `.then` method.

Comment: `err` is not defined. Also, not handling the rejection converts the promise into a successfully resolved one.

Answer (score -1):

A non success response will be resolved as a rejected promise so you'll need to handle it as such

```
$http.get('/api/user/' + params).then(function onSuccess(res) {
    // ...
}, function onError(res) {
    if (res.status === 404) {
        // handle the 404 here
    } else {
        return $q.reject(res); // don't swallow the error if it's unexpected
    }
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and explanation. I am checking out the resources you provided as well. I updated my code in the original question. I am having the same result.

Comment: @CiscoKidx You've added another `then` method which is **not** what is in my answer above.

Comment: Really? You down voted me because I didn't choose your answer?

Comment: @CiscoKidx no, I don't care which answer you accept, just pointing out that you'd added extra `then` handlers instead of adding the error handler as the second argument